# Font import that isn't working anymore?

Tags: html, css

I got this code that normally works but suddenly it does not, something I miss see that someone else see that's wrong?

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'OCRAExtendedRegular';
src: url('ocraextended.eot?#iefix');
src: url('ocraextended.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('ocraextended.woff') format('woff'),
     url('ocraextended.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('ocraextended.svg#OCRAExtendedRegular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;}
```

After coding this, I put in the html: `font-family:'OCR A Extended';` at the div that's like this: `<div id="left" style="padding-left:90px; margin-top:-67px; color:#ffffff; font-family:'OCR A Extended';">`. 
While typing: "font-family", you can add the font: OCR A Extended. 
The CSS is linked with the webpage so in my opinion I think that there's nothing wrong..

Someone got an idea?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The name that you should call your font by in the CSS is defined in the `@font-face` declaration where it says `font-family`.  You need to reference it with that name exactly:

```
font-family: 'OCRAExtendedRegular';
```

This [documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-fonts/#descdef-font-family) describes how `font-family` works in `@font-face`: it creates an arbitrary name which you can use to reference the font.

Comment: GREAT! it's working now! :) Thanks alot! couldn't think of something that was wrong! Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

**Use this**

`font-family: 'OCRAExtendedRegular';`

instead of

`font-family:'OCR A Extended';`

this will work and also please be sure that the path you have given is correct

Comment: Yep thanks! had the right awnser a little bit before you, but still. thanks!